# Assembly AT&T - Negative flag & Loop+String content fetching

Tags: string, loops, pointers, assembly, x86-64

I've written some assembly code on making a counter to count the length of a string.

The string is `-123`.

I'm having just the one issue:

- My negative check (`cmp %r15, %r14` / `je Negative_counter`) is being bypassed even if I have a negative integer

```
            .data
S:          .string "123"
Result:     .quad 

            .text
            .globl main

main: 
    mov     $S,%rdx             #Storage of string
    mov     $S,%rbx
    mov     Result, %rax        #Location of result storage

    mov     $10, %r8


    mov     $1, %r11            #-1 counter creation with 2s complement
    not     %r11                #negation of 1
    add     $1, %r11            #2's complement complete

    mov     $1, %r12            #-1 counter creation with 2s complement
    not     %r12                #negation of 1
    add     $1, %r12            #2's complement complete, -1 established


#R[rbx] is used here.
Loop1:                          #loop string from end to beginning
    cmp     $0, (%rbx)          #compare base addresss value with null
    je      Counter_Made        #if null, branch to end loop. 
    add     $1, %r11            #increment %r11 by 1 for each digit thats not null (creates counter for 2nd loop)
    add     $1, %rbx            #Next string digit
    jmp     Loop1               #reinitiate loop

#Counter of string made -149, would given counter value of 3

#R[rdx] and r14 is used here.
Counter_Made: 
    cmp     $0,%r11             #check if %r11 is zero
    je      Output              #End program, output null result

    mov     $S, %r14            #move into register 14
    sub     $7, %r14            #Shift to least significant bit

    mov     $13, %r15
    and     $15, %r15


    cmp     %r15, %r14          #Determine negativity/positivity of integer, if <0 value is negative
    je      Negative_counter
    jmp     Positive_loop 

Positive_loop: 
    cmp     %r12,%r11           #End of loop check 
    je      Output              #Store result if loop end condition satisfied

    mov     (%rdx), %r10        #grab first byte in address string
    sub     $30,(%rdx)          #Conversion from 8bitASCII to 2Bit Binary
    and     $15, %r10           #initialize size to match 

Positive_inner_loop: 
    mov     %r11, %r9
    cmp     $0, %r9             #Compare loop length with 0 to see if it needs multiplication 
    je      InnerLoopDone       #Jump to inner loop done once length = 0
    imul    %r8, %r10           #Place holder multiplication


InnerLoopDone:
    add     %r10,%rax
    sub     $1, %r11            #Decrease Length to grab next ten multiplication place holder position
    mov     1(%rdx), %rdx           #next digit position
    jmp     Positive_loop



Negative_counter:
    add     $1,%rdx
    jmp     Negative_loop

Negative_loop: 
    cmp     %r12,%r11
    je      Negative_Complement 
    jmp     Negative_loop

Negative_Complement:
    not     %rdx                #Convert to 2's complement with negation and then + 1
    add     %r14,%rdx
    jmp     Output

Output:
    ret
```

Comment: Note that your question says the string is `-123`, but your code uses `123` (with no minus).  That's not the problem, though.

Comment: duplicate of which of your previous questions?  I'll copy my answer there and delete it here.  (After that, you'll be able to delete your own question).  Another option is to delete the previous question, or just mark it as a duplicate of this.

Comment: If you want to follow Peter's advice, and either close the old question as a duplicate of this one or this one as a duplicate of the old one, that's fine. Just post the link to the other question. But you absolutely cannot obliterate the text of this question, considering someone put effort into answering it.

Comment: FWIW, I totally fail to see what the code is doing. It certainly does not count the length of the string. And if the string is not delimited somehow (e.g., as usual, by a zero byte), how does the code know where the string ends?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about this block of code.  I've re-commented it with less useless comments.  e.g. `move into register 14` doesn't tell you anything you can't tell from the `mov $S, %r14` instruction itself.  Comments should explain what's going on in the algorithm.  Assume that the person reading the comments has a copy of the instruction reference manual available, so only comment on the mechanical details if you're doing something non-obvious.  (Like using a flag that's still set from a few instructions ago).

```
    mov     $S, %r14            # r14 = pointer to the start of the string
    sub     $7, %r14            # r14 = pointer to 7 bytes before the beginning of the string

    mov     $13, %r15
    and     $15, %r15           # r15 = 13 & 0xF = 13


    cmp     %r15, %r14          # 
    je      Negative_counter    # jump if (S-7) == 13

    # jmp     Positive_loop     # this is totally redundant, you don't need a jmp to jump over the blank line before the next block of code.

Positive_loop:
```

Clearly `S-7` (i.e. `&S[-7]` in C syntax) is never going to equal 13, because addresses of things in the .data or .rodata section will never be that close to 0 on Linux.

---

You could have easily seen this with a debugger, by setting a breakpoint or single-stepping until you got to the cmp/je and looking at the contents of those regs.

See the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for a quick explanation of putting gdb into `layout reg` mode where it shows the register values as you single-step.

---

There are probably a lot of other things wrong with your code, too, but it's long and I didn't read it all.

Comment: The original comment on `sub $7, %r14` is "shift to least significant bit". I am flabbergasted why the OP thinks this shifts anything. Although... this could be some kind of misunderstanding of addresses, assuming that at index -7 the least significant byte of the address of S can be found (assuming S points to most significant byte) and that that is the first byte, somehow. Seems like a complete misunderstanding of addresses and strings.